# How to validate and transform array of number or array of array of number in class-validator and class-transformer

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, class-validator, class-transformer

I have case where need to validate and transform value union type of array of number or array of array of number. I've tried using discriminator below but it does not make sense for non object type. coordinates should able to contain `Array<number> | Array<Array<number>>`.

```
export class Geometry {
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => Array, {
    discriminator: {
      property: '__type',
      subTypes: [
        { value: Array, name: 'array' },
        { value: Number, name: 'number' },
      ],
    },
  })
  readonly coordinates: number[] | Array<number[]>;
}
```

Any idea how to implement this in class-validator and class-transformer?

Comment: Christoforus Surjoputro, did you find a solution?

Comment: @mathieu-larose, nope.